# How to refresh div using ajax refresh?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, jsp

I am working on spring mvc controller project in which I am passing data from controller to jsp. And my jsp page has Horizontal tabbed design and after clicking on each tab, I am showing tables.

Currently I have only two tab in my design. As soon as I click `TEST1` tab, it shows `Table1` but if I click `TEST2` tab, it shows another table having different columns and data which is `Table2` and it works fine.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veGY9/9/).

And here is my test4.jsp design -

```
<div id='headerDivDash'>
    <h1 id='topHeaderDash'>
        some_image
    </h1>
</div>

<ul id="tabs">
    <li><a href="#" name="tab1">TEST1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="tab2">TEST2</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="content"> 
    <div id="tab1">
        <h2>Test 1</h2>
        <div class="container">
            <c:forEach var="e" items="${testing.machines}">
                <div class="component">
                    <h3>
                        For
                        <c:out value="${e.key}" />
                    </h3>
                    <table class="overflow-y">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>
                                <th>Address</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <c:forEach var="m" items="${e.value}">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>${m.fName}</th>
                                    <td class="color-changer">${m.lName}</td>
                                    <td>${m.address}</td>
                                    <td>${m.email}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </c:forEach>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
            <h2>Test 2</h2>

        <div class="container">
            <c:forEach var="e" items="${testing.machines}">
                <div class="component">
                    <h3>
                        For
                        <c:out value="${e.key}" />
                    </h3>
                    <table class="overflow-y">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>
                                <th>Address</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <c:forEach var="m" items="${e.value}">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>${m.fName}</th>
                                    <td class="color-changer">${m.lName}</td>
                                    <td>${m.address}</td>
                                    <td>${m.email}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </c:forEach>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">&copy Some value</div>
```

I am passing data from controller to jsp page. Now what I would like to do is -

- I would like to refresh both of my tabs which are `tab1 div` and `tab2 div` every 30 seconds using AJAX refresh.
- Also, if I am on `TEST1` tab, and then the refresh is happening, then it should be on `TEST1` tab but suppose if I am on `TEST2` tab, and then the refresh is happening, then it should be on `TEST2` tab.

Below is the jquery I came up with just for `tab1` refresh not sure how would I use it for `tab2` as well but somehow after refresh, I am still seeing the old data and it's not showing the latest data after refresh.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Create overlay and append to body:
    $('<div id="overlay"/>').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: '100%',
        height: $(window).height() + 'px',
        opacity:0.4, 
        background: 'lightgray url(http://bradsknutson.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/page-loader.gif) no-repeat center'
    }).hide().appendTo('body');

    // Execute refresh with interval:
    setInterval(refresh, 30 * 1000);
});

//Create a refresh function:
function refresh(){
    // SHOW overlay
    $('#overlay').show();
    // Retrieve data:
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test4.jsp',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            var content =  $($.parseHTML(data)).filter("#tab1");
            //Replace content inside the div
            $('#tab1').replaceWith(content); # this is not updating my tab div with latest data
            // HIDE the overlay:
            $('#overlay').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

I am not able to see that my `tab1` div is getting refreshed at all. I can see refresh image showing up but somehow tab1 always hold same old data which I see hitting the url for the first time.. Is there something wrong in my jquery?

Also I have noticed one thing which is pretty strange, if I remove `content div and tab1 div` and just refresh `container div` then I am able to see my updated data after refresh and it works fine but if I add `content and tab1 div` and try to refresh `container div`, then it doesn't work at all. So something is wrong for sure..

I am suspecting this is happening because of my css issue I guess which is shown in jsfiddle.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First as u trying to fetch test4.html which is giving 404 error on ajax so  i use test (jsfiddle default ajax mockup). I can see the update on tab1,, about tab2 if u replacing content in "#tab1" at ajax success it will not update tab2 content.

Second donot use replaceWith() this will replace the full element so next time there will be no div element with id="tab1".. instead use this..

```
        if( $("#tabs li:first").attr("id") ==="current"){
        $('#tab1').html("dummy content 1");
        }
        else { $('#tab2').html("dummy content 2"); }
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/veGY9/12/)

Comment: Thanks Neha. In your example what I would be substituting for dummy `content 1` and `dummy content 2` in my example? As I need to load `container div` in both of the tabs. Any idea?

Comment: what is you ajax return ? does its return container div or html content to update inside the container div?

Comment: I guess the only problem is happening because of `container div`. The way you have done is simplest thing to replace anything. In my case, the problem is with container div.

Comment: In my example, I need to reload `container div` in both of my tabs which I have.

Comment: so you ajax return full structure html or only data .. if u give me idea what is ajax o/p i might help u.

Comment: I recently started with this. How do I find out what it is returning? I guess it return back full HTML if I do `alert(data)`.

Comment: u can put console.log(data) and can see in inspect element. and if its html then u can try $(".container")hmtl(data); ..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49911/discussion-between-akiweb-and-neha)